# Copy text onto Windows Clipboard remotely using SSH

Tags: windows, ssh, cmd, clipboard, openssh

I am unable to copy the contents of any text file remotely onto the Windows clipboard via an SSH connection.

I have 2 computers A and B:
Both are Windows OS (A=Win11 and B=Win10)
A uses OpenSSH Client
B uses OpenSSH Server

I need to do the following:

1. Transfer 2 files namely `t.bat` and `t.txt` from A to B (Did this successfully using scp).
2. Then create an SSH connection (use ssh admin@ipofcomputerB)->enter password.
3. Then go into cmd of Computer B.
4. Then run `t.bat`.

`t.bat` contains the following:

```
@echo off
type "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\t.txt"|clip
```

I am able to do steps 1->4.
But the contents of `t.txt` do not reach the Windows clipboard even after running `t.bat`.

However if I run `t.bat` locally on Computer B s' CMD (i.e not via the SSH connection setup b/w computer A and B), then the contents get successfully copied into the clipboard.

Is this an access-level or permission related problem? I am unable to identify the root reason for this.

I even wrote a python program as below using pyperclip and then tried to remotely execute via SSH- CMD prompt of Computer B from Computer A i.e:

```
python t.py
```

Same error :
If I do it remotely via the SSH connection ->no copy into clipboard
If I run the python program locally ->successfully copied

Maybe I need to change some stuff in sshd_config.
Currently I do not use any keys, and just use the password to login.

Comment: Why do you need a text in the clipboard? Is it possible to automate your task in another way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that each user session gets it own clipboard.

Tested with **setclip.bat**

```
@echo off
echo Hello %time% | clip
```

And **getclip.bat**

```
@echo off
powershell -sta "add-type -as System.Windows.Forms; [windows.forms.clipboard]::GetText()"
```

You get different results from the clipboard for each session.

If you really need the text in the local windows session clipboard, you could use a simple batch file which loads the content from a text file.

```
FROM SSH> echo Content > myclip.txt

FROM Windows> clip < myclip.txt
```